# GeoMesa Import GeoJSON

Tags: geomesa

I am trying to import a geojson file with the US States.
The geojson file has 3 fields. gid,state_abbr, and geometry.

I submit this code

```
bin/geomesa-cassandra ingest --contact-point 127.0.0.1:9042 --key-space mykeyspace --catalog mycatalog --converter state-json --spec state-json states.geojson
```

and get back

```
INFO  Creating schema state-json
INFO  Running ingestion in local mode
INFO  Ingesting 1 file with 1 thread
[                                                            ]   0% complete 
0 ingested 57 failed in 00:00:01
INFO  Local ingestion complete in 00:00:01
INFO  Ingested 0 features and failed to ingest 57 features.
```

My converter file is

```
"state-json" = {
  type         = "json"
  id-field     = "$gid"
  feature-path = "$.features"
  fields = [
    { name = "gid",   json-type = "integer",  path = "$.gid",             }
    { name = "state_abbr", json-type = "string",   path = "$.state_abbr", }
    { name = "geom",  json-type = "geometry", path = "$.geometry",    }
  ]
}
```

and my spec file is

```
"state-json" = {
  attributes = [
    { name = "gid", type = "Integer"    }
    { name = "state_abbr",  type = "String" }
    { name = "geom",   type = "Geometry"  }
  ]
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to try:

First, for the paths, GeoJSON has a 'properties' bit in the path.  That'll mean that the gid might be '$.properites.gid', etc.

Next, since 'gid' is an integer, and id's are strings, you'll want to do 
id-field = "toString($gid)".

Lastly, to debug more, can you peek at logs/geomesa.log?